# Diffie-Hellmann why bigger primes prefered over bigger pseudorandom secrets?

Tags: diffie-hellman

So I have build an application which purpose is to demonstrate Diffie-Hellman. I don't fully understand some of the arguments for the sizes of the numbers used in the algorithm.
It seems like there is a general concensus that the prime used should be atleast 1024 bit, more preferably 2048 bit.
Doesn't that just make the generated secret numbers used to generating the public keys more restricted? I will demonstrate my confusion with a 256 bit prime and a 128 bit prime.

If we have prime $$a=4386627406713377435825230798660911668$$ and prime $$b=84612854289522649808987883973782867615634280117273501953794963789129643590017$$ I would think it is obvious that the client and server have more freedom to generate larger pseudorandom numbers in case we use prime `a` rather than `b`. And because 
$$a^{60}=3.371668438049062723431E+2198$$
$$b^{28}=9.294321182028859888665E+2153$$
So in case you use prime `a` generating the secret `60` was arguably identical to using prime `b` and using secret `28`.

When attacking Diffie-Hellman, (I know there is more efficient approaches) would be to just brute force it. Take the public keys generated from the client and the server and check whether $$a^{1..n}\mod primitive_-root = public_-key$$
in case of both using prime `a` and prime `b` I would thereby speculate that using a larger prime would then take fewer tries to compromise, but more computationally heavy ones.

I suspect that I am either missing something, or have a wrong perspective. To make this question more concise:

> Why is it adviced to use larger primes, rather than larger pseudorandom number taking the above into consideration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a public prime modulus $p$ (the question's $a$ and $b$), participants to Diffie-Hellmann key exchange choosing secret $x$ do not send $y=p^x$ as considered in the question (which invalidates the reasoning made).

Instead, participants send $y=g^x\bmod p$, where $g$ is some public constant. $g=2$ will do (or will often do, depending on variant of DH). By definition of $\bmod$, it holds that $0\le y<p$, and that $p$ divides $g^x-y$. The later number is extremely large (it has over $0.3\,p$ decimal digits thus won't fit any computer), yet we can compute $g^x\bmod p$ easily using well-established [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) techniques. In Python, that can be with `pow(g,x,p)`.

> Why is it advised to use larger primes, rather than larger pseudorandom number taking the above into consideration?

We can choose $p$ and $g$ in a way such that there is a one-one correspondence between $x$ and $y$ in $[1,p)$: we choose with $p$ and $q=(p-1)/2$ prime, then choose $g$ with $1<g<p-1$ and $g^q\bmod p\ne1$. In another common setup, the later is changed to $g^q\bmod p=1$, and there is now a one-one correspondence between an $x$ in $[1,q)$ and one $y$ out of two in $[1,p)$.

In both cases, the larger $p$, the wider the choice of $x$ and $y$. Thus we do not have to choose between large $p$ and a large set of random numbers.